# C function to remove string

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Total beginner here trying to wrap my head around some basic C knowledge before taking an in-depth Objective-C course in few weeks, so I apologize if this is pedestrian..

The assignment is to create a function that takes three arguments: a source string, an integer to start deletion from that string, and another integer that tells the function how many characters to delete. The example as given in the book is the starting string "the wrong son" and then 4 and 6, leaving just "the son".

My thinking is to create two separate strings based on the first word and second, then concatenate them together. So far, I'm only able to extract "the", and my second for loop apparently does nothing. This is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char text[]="the wrong son";
    void removeString (char[], int, int);
    int s, l;

    printf("Enter starting point for removal: ");
    scanf("%d",&s);

    printf("\nEnter lenght of removal: ");
    scanf("%d",&l);

    removeString(text, s, l);

    printf("\nString after removal = %s",text);

    return 0;
}

void removeString (char s1[], int s, int l)
{

    printf("s1 = %s, s=%d, l=%d\n", s1, s, l);

    char s2[]="";
    char s3[]="";

    int i,j;

    for (; i<s; ++i)
        {
            s2[i]=s1[i];
        }

    printf("\n");

    for (; j>l; ++j)
        {
            s3[j]=s1[j];
        }

    printf("s2 = %s, s3 = %s", s2, s3);
}
```

I'm properly confused.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to initialise `i` and `j` like `int i; for (i = ...; i < s; ++i) {...}`.

Comment: Please use descriptive names for variables, your code is hard to understand.

Comment: You're not making `s2` and `s3` big enough. When you don't specify the size of the array, and initialize it with a string, it makes it just big enough to hold that string. So `char s2[] = "";` is equivalent to `char s2[1] = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeString (char text[], int start, int length) {
  int n = strlen(text), i;
  for (i = start+length; i <= n; i++) {
    text[i-length] = text[i];
  }
}


int main (void) {
  char text[] = "the wrong son";
  int start, length;
  printf("Original text: \"%s\"\n", text);

  printf("Enter starting point for deletion: ");
  scanf("%d", &start);
  printf("\nEnter number of characters to delete: ");
  scanf("%d", &length);

  removeString(text, start, length);
  printf("After deletion: \"%s\"\n", text);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciation on all the responses

Answer (score 2):

Creating separate arrays for this purpose is not the best approach, IMHO. Instead, an altogether better an cleaner approach will be

1. Receive the array, start index and skip index values.
2. calculate the length of the array using `strlen()`.
3. put the value in (*start index*+*skip index*) location to *start index* location.
4. increment the *start index* by 1.
5. continue the step 3 and 4 until the array length runs out, i.e., the latest (*start index*+*skip index*) points to the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are not objects, they are just arrays of chars in memory.

In your case, removing a part of the string can be done by a simple memory move:

```
void removeString (char string[], int start, int length)
{
    int from = start + length;

    // You should do some verifications here, like start < string length, etc. 
    while (string[from] != 0)
        string[start++] = string[from++];
    string[start] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
void removeString (char s1[], int s, int l)
{

printf("s1 = %s, s=%d, l=%d\n", s1, s, l);

char s2[]="";
char s3[]="";

int i,j;

for (; i<s; ++i)
{
    s2[i]=s1[i];
}

printf("\n");

for (; j>l; ++j)
{
    s3[j]=s1[j];
}

printf("s2 = %s, s3 = %s", s2, s3);
}
```

Has a two important problems,

1. You didn't allocate enough space for `s2` or `s3`.
2. You never initialize `i` or `j`.

Try this instead

```
void removeString (char *source, int offset, int length)
{
    int    i;   
    size_t source_length;
    if (source == NULL)
        return;
    source_length = strlen(source);
    if ((offset >= source_length) || (source_length - offset < length))
        return;
    printf("source = %s, offset = %d, length = %d\n", source, offset, length);
    for (i = 0 ; i < offset ; ++i)
        result[i] = source[i];    
    for (j = 0 ; source[j + offset] != '\0' ; ++i)
       result[j] = source[j + offset];  
    printf("s2 = %s\n", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will edit string s1 in place
void removeString(char *s1, int s, int l)
{
  int len = strlen(s1);
  // Abort if start pos beyond end of string, or nothing to remove
  if (s >= len || l < 1)
    return;
  // Terminate original string at pos s
  s1[s] = 0;
  // Finished if s+l beyond end of string
  if (s+l >= len)
    return;
  // Otherwise concat rest to 1st part
  strcat(s1, s1+s+l);
}
```